# R markdown themes not knitting

Tags: r, compiler-errors, r-markdown

Currently I'm working on automating a project. Problem: The program is failing to knit because of the following code:

```
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: ref.pptx
```

The error code states:

> Could not find shape for Powerpoint content
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 63
> Execution halted

When I put my presentation into Google Slides, the theme works without a problem. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have the `ref.pptx` file in the same exact parent directory as the .Rmd file? Rmarkdown has a few templates to replace powerpoint, like [ioslides](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/ioslides-presentation.html), [revealjs](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/revealjs.html), but understand if you have to use powerpoint for work